# Change order date in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, sales

I'm currently creating orders in Magento to put all our orders in the Magento system, since we sell our products through multiple channels and prefer to have a clear overview of all orders in Magento. I would like to put the right order date in Magento aswell, but I can't find a way to change the order date of a created order.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

`created_at`  in `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_grid` table

```
// this may work for order... You will still need to update the grid value
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
$order->setData('created_at`, {date format});
```